# PHP compare 2 different arrays by a value and find differences

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 very completely different arrays:

1 looks like this ($fromBackend):

```
array:3 [
  114466 => array:1 [
    "BrandID" => 136,
    "record" => 114466
  ]
  114467 => array:1 [
    "BrandID" => 1,
    "record" => 114467
  ]
  114468 => array:1 [
    "BrandID" => 2,
    "record" => 114468
  ]
]
```

The other one looks like this ($fromFrontend):

```
array:2 [
  0 => Entity {#920
    #id: 117
    #brandId: 1
  }
  1 => Entity {#915
    #id: 118
    #brandId: 2
  }
]
```

Now as you can see I need to find the "record" of the first array where the brandId's dont match so in this case I need to find "114466" because BrandId => 136 doesn't exist in the second array

Here's what I've got:

```
$recordsToDelete = [];
foreach ($fromBackend as $fromBackendItem) {
    foreach ($fromFrontend as $fromFrontendItem) {
        if ($fromBackendItem['BrandID'] !== $brand->getBrandId()) {
            $recordsToDelete[] = $fromBackendItem['record'];
        }
    }
 }

 dd($recordsToDelete);
```

This gets me a weird results probably cause I am looping too much:

```
0 => 114466
1 => 114466
2 => 114467
3 => 114468
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding every record to your `$recordsToDelete` array because any time the `brandId` values don't match, you add the record and, since the `brandId` values don't match for *all* records, that means that condition is always true at least once for every record. Instead, compare all the `brandId` values from the front end for each back end record and *only* add the record to `$recordsToDelete` if it doesn't match *any* other `brandId` value. For example:

```
$recordsToDelete = array();
foreach ($fromBackend as $backendItem) {
    foreach ($fromFrontEnd as $frontendItem) {
        if ($frontendItem->brandId == $backendItem['BrandID']) break;
    }
    if ($frontendItem->brandId != $backendItem['BrandID']) $recordsToDelete[] = $backendItem['record'];
}
print_r($recordsToDelete);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 114466
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2UWPC)

If `$fromFrontEnd` could be empty the above code will raise an undefined variable error. You can work around that by checking it using the null coalescing operator e.g.

```
if (($frontendItem->brandId ?? -1) != $backendItem['BrandID']) $recordsToDelete[] = $backendItem['record'];
```

or by using an explicit `found` flag:

```
foreach ($fromBackend as $backendItem) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($fromFrontEnd as $frontendItem) {
        if ($frontendItem->brandId == $backendItem['BrandID']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) $recordsToDelete[] = $backendItem['record'];
}
```

although it would probably be simpler to just not execute the outer `foreach` loop unless `!empty($fromFrontEnd)`;

Demo of above 2 solutions on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vqlLt)

Comment: I don't think I can access `$frontendItem->brandId` since it's outside the loop, in the second if?

Comment: @michael at the end of the second loop, `$frontendItem` will contain the last element in the `$fromFrontEnd` array. Unless there was a match (which caused the loop to break), the `brandId` from this value will not be the same as the one from `$backendItem` and so the value will be added to the `$recordsToDelete` array. Try playing with the `brandId` values in my demo, you can see how it works.

Comment: it's just when i run the code in my application I get an `Undefined variable: brand`

Comment: @michael I'm not sure where `brand` is coming from? It doesn't exist in my code...

Comment: woops I am sorry I mean `$frontendItem` on this line `if ($frontendItem->brandId != $backendItem['BrandID']) $recordsToDelete[] = $backendItem['record'];`

Comment: That could only happen if `$fromFrontEnd` is empty

Comment: yes, that's a possibility too, i have an other block code for this, i will fix it one second

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise. You can work around that using an explicit `found` flag, see https://3v4l.org/IR9JD or see my edited answer for other ideas.